# How do I get number of nights with Carbon/Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon, laravel-6.2

I am trying to build a hotel booking module with Laravel. I don't have an idea on how I could calculate a rate with number of nights with [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon). 
For example, I have two dates:

```
$date1 = Carbon::parse('2019-07-25 12:00:00');
$date2 = Carbon::parse('2019-07-29 10:00:00');
$days  = $date2->diffInDays($date1); 
$nights = ??
```

How am I able to get how many nights are between these two dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it with DateTime class

```
    $date1 = new DateTime('2019-07-25 12:00:00');
    $date2 = new DateTime('2019-07-29 10:00:00');
    $nightsDays = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```

Comment: Technically it's correct. But is there a way to use it with Carbon?

Comment: Never mind, I just found out that Carbon is basically an enhanced version of the DateTime functions. Means Basically I could just call `Carbon::parse()` instead of `new DateTime`

Comment: The solution is not correct. It delivers the difference in days, not the number of nights in the interval.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the time on the arrival day to 00:00 guarantees a correct calculation of the number of nights in the interval.
Carbon is a extension of DateTime. All Methods of Datetime you can also use with Carbon.

Example

```
$dateCheckin = new DateTime('2019-07-25 18:00:00');
$dateCheckout = new DateTime('2019-07-26 10:00:00');  //next Day Morning

$nightsDays = $dateCheckin
  ->setTime(0,0)
  ->diff($dateCheckout)
  ->format("%a")
;

echo $nightsDays;  //1
```

Without set time to 00:00 you receive with this data the incorrect result 0.